# Setting ppEnabledExtensionNames causes Vulkan crash

Tags: c++, runtime-error, vulkan

I'm trying to learn Vulkan through vulkan-tutorial.com, and I am stuck on the [Validation Layer](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers) tutorial. For some reason, setting `ppEnabledExtensionNames` to any `std::vector`'s `.data()` crashes the program.

The problematic stuff is in `debug.cpp`

Here's a link: https://pastebin.com/j7NTQsH0

If somebody could *please* look at the code and tell me what's wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the relevant code here and not behind 2 links.

Comment: I don't have 10 reputation, and therefore cannot post more than 2 links.

Comment: C'mon, people. Don't downvote without at least posting WHY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the scope of `validationLayers`. It's local to the `initDebugging` function, while you're using the `createInfo` updated in that function (pointing to that local vector) outside of it in `initInstance`, and at that point the `validationLayers` vector is out of scope and with that also all values that `createInfo->ppEnabledLayerNames` points to.

To fix this you need to copy or declare the values from `validationLayers` so that they're still valid when you call `vkCreateInstance`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now! I figured that it was just a stupid mistake like that.